# Converting BitmapImage to IplImage and vice versa

Tags: c#, wpf, image-processing

I have application in WPF and I need to download an image from controls **Image** convert this image to IplImage, because I need to do operations on image. Then convert to **Image** and send to controls.

So I need to convert Image to IplImage, do operation and convert back and my question is how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried some research on google or stack overflow? There are many answers to your question.

Comment: Yes, but only I learned that he would have to convert BitmapImage to Bitamp and finally to IplImage and vice versa. And I want to be a better way.